# Are British National Grid (BNG) 1km grid shapefiles displayed accurately in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, shapefile, ordnance-survey, grids-graticules

I have downloaded the UK Ordinance Survey's 1km grids in shapefile format for ArcMap.

If you need to download them to have a look first you can find them here look for link in the first Answer to the Question [Ordnance Survey grids - download or generate?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/21/ordnance-survey-grids-download-or-generate).

They 'supposedly' represent 1km grids however here is where the first problem begins. If I calculate their dimensions and areas in ArcMap their size differ from one another. How is this possible are they not supposed to be regularly spaced every 1km?

The second problem I encounter is - of course as a result of the first problem - that if I try to divide the areas into smaller sections they grid would now shift slightly to one side.

Can you please advise if there is a way to solve this problem and/or if you get the same results?

Answer (score 4):

After calculating areas of the [1km grid shapefile](https://github.com/charlesroper/OSGB_Grids) rectangles, I **can confirm** that the single cells are **not precisely 1km²**. The **error is small**, though. If your errors are larger, it is possible that your problem is related to a different issue (possible reprojection errors).

### Small errors in the source dataset

Most of the calculated areas are less than 10m² off. *(Mean value is 1km², standard deviation  is 7m²;  there are some outliers (corresponding to E-W-oriented lines in the far north): 210 out of 286000 rectangles have errors >100m², the largest errors being about 130m².)*

Given the fact that on a 1km² rectangle, a 1mm increase in width propagates to  a 1m² area increase, *I am not sure if these shapefiles were designed to have a sub-meter precision.* I have checked the coordinates of one of the most inaccurate grid cells: x error was 2 mm, y error 134 mm.

The error seems to be systematical, maybe due to inaccuracies during the initial generation of the grid coordinates: *(See detail picture, blue/green shows "too small" areas, orange/red shows "too large" ones)*

[image: 1km BNG shapefile, showing calculated area for each grid cell. Colors highlight errors from ideal 1km² area]

Although the error is pretty small, it seems unnecessary as grid cells are precisely defined. If you need more precise grid cells, either re-create them (inherit the naming scheme from the provided shapefile), or  *alter the coordinates of the individual shapes* by rounding to the closest integer number. (This works because all errors are smaller than 0.5m, and linear unit is meter as the coordinates are given in *OSGB 1936* projected coordinate system.) **In fact, all Northing / Easting coordinates of the OSGB 1km grid should be multiples of 1000.**)

However, with the grid lines being misaligned by a maximum of 13cm (less then 1cm for most grid lines), I would consider this a rather minor issue, which can *most likely be neglected for many scenarios*.

### Possible coordinate transformation issue

Note that the [British national grid](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Great_Britain_National_Grid/003r0000002z000000/) uses the **OSGB 1936 datum**. This is based on the **Airy 1860 ellipsoid**. (See the [OSNG wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordnance_Survey_National_Grid) for an overview information about datum shifts.)

In general, *no transformation is without error, especially in the sub-meter scale. Do not perform transformations if you do not have to use them*; for best precision, **stay in original OSGB36 as long as possible** and reproject in a final step, after calculations.

For reference, I projected the shapefile to *PCS UTM30N (WGS84)* and calculated areas afterwards. The error was much higher, most cells were about 140m² off from 1km².
Calculating areas after projection to *GCS WGS84* produced an even larger error (approx. 650m² for most cells)

If you for some reason cannot use the original coordinate system for your project, eventually based on a different ellipsoid (e.g. UTM 30N with WGS84ellipsoid), check if *coordinate transformations* have been applied correctly.

For on-the-fly transformation, go to *"Layer Properties" -> "coordinate system"* -> *"Transformations..."* . Choose "GCS_OSGB_1936" in the *"Convert from"* box. The *"Into"* field should be your destination projection (e.g. GCS_WGS_84). Select one of the methods. (There is an [overview article about transformations at ESRI blogs](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2009/05/06/about-geographic-transformations-and-how-to-choose-the-right-one/), the [knowledge base article #21327](http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/21327) for a detailed list of transformations, and also a [GIS.SE question that deals with transformations and OSGB](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/16678/reproject-tm65-to-osgb-in-arcgis)).
For a permanent transformation of the shapefile, use *"Arc Toolbox" -> "Data management Tools" -> "Projections and Transformations" -> "Feature" -> "Project"*.

Comment: lavarider - thanks very much for checking. The problem I have at the moment is that I need to use/create a grid (100m - 200m - 1000m etc) over parts of the UK which will be extremely accurate and where all grids will be integers. Ultimately I will be requiring the data in lat/lon format using the WGS_1984 projection however most of the data I have to start with is in BNG. What is your advice in this case. I need to make sure that the data can be transformed from BNG to WGS_1984 back and forth multiple times without losing precision. Is this something possible or errors will always be produced?

Comment: If the cited shapefile is too defective for your case, you could create your own. But maybe it is an option to do your task without a specific, heavy-weight "grid shapefile", but _calculate your custom grid coordinates directly from OSGB Northing and Easting coordinates?_ Do you really need a shapefile?   - For precision issues (and loss) of _back and forth-transformation_ I suggest you could ask a new question, providing more details about the specific workflow.

Comment: Hi, new question created

Comment: Hi lavarider, I have tried to open a new question as you have suggested but unfortunately has been flagged as 'duplicate' which is not at all. Could you please have a look at my question? Many thanks

Comment: Please refer to the high-quality comments in cffk's answer, which are dealing with the projection issues in more detail (especially: _try to stay on Airy ellipsoid_). I was able to contribute to the initial shp-accuracy question - to the detailed difficulties of projection issues, with the precision you seem to look for, my contributions will probably stay minor.  However, try to [ask well written questions](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) - in particular, it would be helpful if you are more clear about _a well defined level of precision_ that you require.

Answer (score 4):

Let's stick with the UK ellipsoid + datum (to avoid datum transformation
issues).  You will inevitably have the "problem" is that the Ordnance
Survey grids are defined on the OS projection which is a transverse
Mercator projection with central longitude 2°W and central scale
0.9996012717.  The scale variation over Britain is roughly 0.9996 to
1.0002 (more in the Hebrides).  On the central meridian a "1km x 1km"
grid is actually 1000.4m x 1000.4m (on the Airy ellipsoid) and so its area
is about 800 m<sup>2</sup> more than 1 km<sup>2</sup>.

The normal way to deal with this discrepancy is to do all your analysis
in the OSGB coordinate system (essentially converting the ellipsoid to a
plane).  However, you always need to be aware that the actual distances
and areas will need to be adjusted according to the local scale.

Comment: The main issue that I have here is that the grids will have to be regular in WGS_1984. If I want to avoid discrepancies with regards to a grid created using WGS_1984, but some of the data is projected and gridded using BNG, how can I go about and do this? Let me know if this is not clear and I'll explain differently.

Comment: You could transform the data to WGS84 (carefully!).  However, I think you are assuming that 1km x 1km grids for the national grid must measure exactly 1km by 1km.  They don't (see my answer) and they can't (because you can't flatten the earth onto a plane -- which is what the national grid does -- without distorting lengths).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If you dont mind I have a few questions I would like to ask you in regards. What do you mean by 'carefully'? Which is the best way to do this? If I ultimately want the grids to be 200m2 when in WGS_1984, should I design the grids in WGS84 first and then convert them into BNG gather compile the data and then go back to WGS84 or should I do something else? And do you have any suggestions regarding the methods to use? Thanks very much

Comment: Your goal -- a grid of (200m)^2 squares on WGS84 -- is an impossible one.  You can't put such a grid on the WGS84 ellipsoid without some distortion.  So you'll need to modify your goal before I can offer any meaningful help.

Comment: +1.  These comments directly answer the duplicate question at http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/85111/664, too.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. I would need to refer you here http://www.mmm.ucar.edu/wrf/users/docs/user_guide_V3/users_guide_chap3.htm (look for step 1) here a resolution is defined dx/dy. I would like to be able to define the grids in ArcMap instead of doing it in WPS first. Does this make sense?

Comment: It looks as though WPS uses a grid in some projected space (Lambert conformal conic in the example).  If you can you use transverse Mercator, then I would recommend using the OS national grid as the underlying projection (together with the corresponding ellipsoid and datum).  That way you can line up your grid with the OS grid.  (And don't expect the lengths and areas of these grids to be constant when mapped back to the ellipsoid.)

Comment: I see that WPS is used as part of a simulation system.  Probably that places restrictions on the projections that are supported.  In that case, you'll have to do your work with a grid defined on Lambert conformal conic (probably).  The prom.4 library (and the cs2cs utility) offers the ability to transform between projections and datums.

Comment: The only Projection that should be used for the UK and/or other mid latitude countries is Lambert conformal. The output files are given in lat lon and I used WGS_1984 in ArcGIS to render the data. Is this incorrect? Should I use a different projection/datum? Is there a way to then create grids which will be consistent as far as you know. As far as I have seen if I create a grid in WPS using Lambert and set a resolution that will create matching size grids...

Comment: I still don't understand what you're up to.  Your statement that only
Lambert conformal can be used at mid-latitudes is false.  The UK (and
much of the US and Europe) uses transverse Mercator.  I still think it's
a mistake to transform the UK coordinates to WGS84, if you can avoid
doing so.  You say that they "have to be in WGS84", but I wonder what
this is based on.  What's the matter with just transforming the UK 1km
(or 200m) grid to lat/long on the Airy ellipsoid.  This transformation
is accurately reversible (round trip error is around 10^-8 m).

Comment: This is an extract from the WPS manual "the Lambert conformal projection is well-suited for mid-latitude domains, and the Mercator projection is good for low-latitude domains or domains with predominantly west-east extent". Nobody uses Mercator for mid-latitude in NWPs. This is why I have been wondering if and how it is possible to get round this problem as from what I can see this is not really possible but then again you may know more than me and this is what I was hoping for...

Comment: There's a variant of Mercator called "transverse Mercator".  It may be the most commonly used conformal projection for large scale mapping.  Look it up in Wikipedia.  It's well suited for any area with an E-W extent of 1000km or less (for example the British Isles).  (Larger areas are dealt with by dividing them into N-S strips.)

Comment: Cffk- I appreciate your help. I really do, however I think we're going a bit off topic here. WPS only accepts the type of projections I referred to; I know there are other projections but the point here is not to use other projections but to be able to obtain comparable grids.

Comment: The interrelation between WPS and your requirements escapes me.  You can certainly transform between the UK grid system and some suitably chosen Lambert projection (the distortions will be greater than TM).  I still advise against a datum transformation if that's possible.  proj.4 will do the change of projections you need.