# Difference in ONS area and area calculation in GIS-software

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, shape-area

I have an [official shapefile](https://data.gov.uk/dataset/cd0777d5-fb38-46b8-a721-c03d28a9ab1a/regions-december-2015-full-clipped-boundaries-in-england) from the ONS (Office for National Statistics) in the BNG (British National Grid) projection.

It has an `st_areaha` attribute column - I understand this is the area in square meters. When I calculate the area using the attribute calculator in QGIS or ARCH (in a BNG projection), I get similar results between softwares, but different from the official attribute column. See below (in square km for easier numbers):

[image]

(NOTE: The grey column is just a test to see if projecting to WG48 would get closer areas numbers, but that isn't it either, so do ignore.)

**Any ideas on why the official / calculated area values are so different?**

Comment: related https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/85043/are-british-national-grid-bng-1km-grid-shapefiles-displayed-accurately-in-arcm (Airy 1860 ellipsoid)